# Looking for a way to begin a proof on the order of an element in a group of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $n>2$, prove that $n-1$ is an element of order $2$ in the group of units $U(n)$.

I attempted to begin the proof by stating that if $n-1$ is of order $2$, then we can write that $(n-1)^2 = e$ where $e$ is the identity element of $U(n)$.

I'm unsure of where to take this idea or if there's a better way to begin this proof. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're asked to proved that $n-1$ is an element of order $2$, so it's not a good idea to start with that as your hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

We prove $(n-1)^2=1_{\small U(n)}$

Observe  that $$(n-1)^2=n^2+1-2n \equiv 1(\text{mod}\;n)$$ since $n \vert n^2-2n$